# Is there an alternative to compiz?

Tags: 11.04, unity, compiz, alternative

Can I find a good replacement for compiz? Compiz in 11.04 with unity is laggy

Answer (score 3):

You can start with *Ubuntu classic (no effect)* that use `metacity` as window manager.

But this means to not have unity.

Answer (score 1):

The only alternative to compiz that I know is kwin.

Comment: kwin isn't so good in a Gnome environment. kwin is designed for KDE.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using unity 2d, you have many other options

[Openbox](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/openbox) [image: Install openbox]: A very lightweight WM. Used by default in LXDE

[Fluxbox](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/fluxbox) [image: Install Fluxbox]: Yet another Lightweight WM

[Awesome](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/awesome) [image: Install Awesome]: A lightweight tiled WM

And many others.

Answer (score 0):

No, Unity is a plugin for Compiz. You could try unity 2D or Ubuntu classic. There is also Gnome-Shell which uses mutter. That is suppose to be less resource intensive.

Comment: Gnome-shell is laggy on my rather new laptop (i5 2.5ghz, nvidia 330m) - it's probably not even close to "ready" yet.