# Desktop not showing after playing with compiz

Tags: compiz

Having successfully installed Ubuntu 11.04 I decided to look into improving look and feel of the unity desktop.  I could find no option to introduce any nice effects with the standard install, but a google session suggested Compiz would do the job.  I installed this and selected the "Wobbly windows" option and this worked fine.

After a while I thought I'd try some of the other available effects (can't remember which but may have been cube desktop) but this resulted in no windows showing at all.  I now have just blank wall paper with no icons or menus.  There are no error messages and right clicking the desktop produces a small context menu but nothing else. Rebooting brings me back to a blank desktop with just wallpaper.

I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following commands in terminal (CTRL+ALT+T)

```
unity --reset
unity --replace
```

or instead of second command just reboot your box.

Be carefull with Compiz. Some of the features are not really working well with Unity ie. Cube plugin.

Comment: Thank for the reply.  CTRL+ALT+T does nothing.  No errors, just nothing but a brief flash as if a window was about to appear but then just the wallpaper again.  I can change the desktop background and create documents using the right click menu so I don't think its completely broken!

Comment: Try to right click on a desktop and create launcher for terminal. In command field write gnome-desktop. Then launch terminal and follow the answer above. You might need to reenable wall plugin in Compiz when you restart.

Comment: Many thanks - All working again now after a reboot.

Comment: Command I ment was gnome-terminal not gnome-desktop, sorry for that.

Comment: No problem - now all sorted.  BTW Is there a better / more stable app I should use rather than compiz?

Comment: You can try this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/41009/is-there-an-alternative-to-compiz but Unity is plugin for Compiz so there isn't a good alternative.