# Compiz doesn't work after trying to enable the desktop cube

Tags: 11.10, compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop not showing after playing with compiz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60299/desktop-not-showing-after-playing-with-compiz)

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 Desktop on my Acer ASPIRE 5742ZG laptop, so I tried to follow the steps of this video to install Compiz ( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yjTP8BGjn_A ). Then I tried to use it but it doesn't work! Before installing Ubuntu 11.10 I had Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and it worked on it.

Comment: we need more info about your hardware - please look at this question and add these details into your question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Comment: If you actually installed CompizConfigSettingsManager as shown in that video then you will find it by searching for compiz in the search panel of the Dash. You should understand that there is a big difference between 10.04 and 11.10 and many of the special effects in compiz do not work very well at the moment in 11.10. In fact they may break your desktop. I have found that wobbly windows works but I have not tried other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Fresh installs don't include it with Compiz. You should install it via the terminal or the Ubuntu software center.

Via the terminal you should type:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-setting-manager
```

Then, enter your password and wait.

Via the Ubuntu software manager you should type `compiz` and then install it.

I hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install compiz on Ubuntu 11.10, it's already installed.

Comment: so how can i activate the cube or the ather effects ?

Comment: @TheMurdre activating the Cube in Unity is not supported officially, and though there are guides all over the internet, I would suggest you ask a separate question or edit this one to reflect what you are really asking. BTW there are many questions covering how to customize compiz on this site already.